# How to combine and get sum from three different related tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, left-join, inner-join

There are three related tables:
operations (id, name)
pricelists (id, operations_id (link to operations table), cost)
accounting (id, pricelists_id (link to pricelists table), quantity)

How to get table, like

```
NAME            SUMMARY_COST            SUMMARY_QUANTITY
milling         result of 2*750                2
threading       result of 1*444                1
...                     ...                   ...
overall         2*750+1*444+...             2+1+...
```

I trying to group for two tables at a start:

```
select operations.name, sum(pricelists.cost) total
from operations
left join pricelists on pricelists.operations_id*accounting_quantity = operations.id*accounting.quantity
group by operations.id
```

but it is not worked yet

A little database:

```
CREATE TABLE operations (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                         name VARCHAR (100));
CREATE TABLE pricelists (id INT PRIMARY KEY,  operations_id INT NOT NULL, cost DECIMAL(10,2),
                  FOREIGN KEY (operations_id) REFERENCES  operations (id));
CREATE TABLE accounting  (id INT PRIMARY KEY, pricelists_id INT NOT NULL, quantity INT,
                        FOREIGN KEY (pricelists_id) REFERENCES  pricelists (id));


INSERT INTO operations (name) VALUES
    ('milling'),
    ('threading'),
    ('grinding'),
    ('welding'),
    ('brazing'),
    ('soldering'),
    ('riveting');

INSERT INTO pricelists (id, operations_id, cost) VALUES
    (1, 2, 750),
    (2, 1, 444),
    (3, 3, 123),
    (4, 4, 450),
    (5, 5, 375),
    (6, 6, 250),
    (7, 7, 232);

INSERT INTO accounting (id, pricelists_id, quantity) VALUES
    (1, 7, 2),
    (2, 2, 5),
    (3, 4, 2),
    (4, 1, 1),
    (5, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consder:

```
select o.name, sum(a.quantity * pl.cost) total, sum(a.quantity) quantity
from operations o
left join pricelists pl on pl.operations_id = o.id
left join accounting a  on a.pricelists_id = pl.id
group by o.name
```

You can generate the summary row by just adding `with rollup` at the very end of the query.

Comment: Thank you! It works. It is possible to add last line "Overall", which presents sum of columns?

Comment: @antonio_fergusson: this is addressed in the answer. Just add `with rollup` at the very end of the query.